# Symfony FOSRESTBundle expose on condition

Tags: symfony, annotations, fosrestbundle

I have one Entity (Restaurant) with the following property

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Review", mappedBy="restaurant")
 *
 * @Serializer\Expose
 * @Serializer\Groups({"all"})
 *
 */
private $reviews;
```

and in the Review entity i have the following property

```
/**
 * @var bool
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="is_accepted", type="boolean")
 *
 * @Serializer\Expose
 * @Serializer\Groups({"all"})
 */
private $isAccepted;
```

obviously my returned JSON is something like this

```
{
    "id": 291,
    "user": {
      "id": 385
    },
    "comment": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
    "is_verified": true,
    "total_rating": 5.5,
    "is_accepted": false
  },
  {
    "id": 292,
    "user": {
      "id": 293
    },
    "comment": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
    "is_verified": true,
    "total_rating": 8,
    "is_accepted": true
  },
```

My question is how can i expose only the is_accepted = true ones ? Is there a direct way to do it or should i filter it manually ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [@VirtualProperty](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#virtualproperty) annotation on a method and only return the reviews from it if it is in fact accepted